# drop indexes from a huge pandas dataframe that cannot possibly fit in memory

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-datareader

I have a file that has 50 million records and I have a list of indexes that I need to drop from the file. If I want to use pandas dataframe to read the file - I can run into memory issues (if I have limited memory). Let's say I do this:

```
df = pd.read_csv('input_file')
df = df.drop(df.index[example_ix_list])
df.to_csv('input_file', index=False)
```

I might run into memory issues:

```
  File "/home/ec2-user/CloudMatcher/cloudmatcher/core/execution/user_interaction.py", line 768, in process
    new_unlabel_df = unlabel_df.drop(unlabel_df.index[list_ix])
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda2/envs/cloudmatch/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 2162, in drop
    dropped = self.reindex(**{axis_name: new_axis})
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda2/envs/cloudmatch/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 2733, in reindex
    **kwargs)
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda2/envs/cloudmatch/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 2515, in reindex
    fill_value, copy).__finalize__(self)
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda2/envs/cloudmatch/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 2679, in _reindex_axes
    fill_value, limit, tolerance)
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda2/envs/cloudmatch/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 2690, in _reindex_index
    allow_dups=False)
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda2/envs/cloudmatch/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 2627, in _reindex_with_indexers
    copy=copy)
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda2/envs/cloudmatch/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.py", line 3897, in reindex_indexer
    for blk in self.blocks]
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda2/envs/cloudmatch/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.py", line 1046, in take_nd
    allow_fill=True, fill_value=fill_value)
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda2/envs/cloudmatch/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/algorithms.py", line 1467, in take_nd
    out = np.empty(out_shape, dtype=dtype)
MemoryError
```

**Q:** Can I read the file in chunks using pandas dataframe and remove indexes using a list? and if so how? or there is some better way that I am missing out.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
pd.read_csv('input_file', skiprows=example_ix_list).to_csv('input_file', index=False)
```

if you still get MemoryError, you can use `chunksize` parameter:

```
example_ix_list = pd.Index(example_ix_list)

for df in pd.read_csv('input_file', chunksize=10**5):
    df.loc[df.index.difference(example_ix_list)] \
      .to_csv('new_file_name', index=False, header=None, mode='a')
```

Comment: I am getting this error if I run the second part. IndexError: index 10006311 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 1000000 when I run with chunksize=10**6 and file has 13762668 records. Anything I am missing?

Comment: thanks it worked. Although when I time it - it's very costly. Maybe because of the difference but it's definitely helpful and working! Great.

Comment: @yguw, you may want to try `np.setdiff1d(df.index.values, example_ix_list.values)` instead of `df.index.difference(example_ix_list)` - this might work slightly faster...

Answer (score -1):

You can pass a chunk_size parameter to read_table() or read_csv() commands:

```
pd.read_csv('fname.csv', sep=',', chunksize=4)
```

Further information in the [documentation](https://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/io.html#iterating-through-files-chunk-by-chunk). Have you checked that?